# where should I locatemy Quartz Code in asp.net

Tags: quartz-scheduler, asp.net-4.0, scheduler

I have an asp.net website and want to do a task once a day.
the task is: sending email to users 2 days before expiration of their registration. 
I used [**Quartz.NET**](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/download.html) version 1.0. I have wrote a sample code that opens a window in each second. Now I don't know where should I locate this code in my asp.net project?! it is now in a simple page. I want it to be independent from pages.

```
    public class DumbJob : IJob
    {
        public DumbJob()
        {
        }

        public void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DumbJob is executing.");
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("NICE");
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // construct a scheduler factory
            ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();

            // get a scheduler
            IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
            sched.Start();

            // construct job info
            JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail("myJob", null, typeof(DumbJob));

            // fire every hour
            Trigger trigger = TriggerUtils.MakeSecondlyTrigger();//.MakeHourlyTrigger();

            // start on the next even hour
            trigger.StartTimeUtc = TriggerUtils.GetEvenSecondDate(DateTime.UtcNow);
            trigger.Name = "myTrigger";

            sched.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think the problem is that it is supposed to be used in a console app or suchlike. The ASP.NET application pool will recycle from time to time making this unusuable.

Comment: is this already resolved? If it is, whats the good solution? i also have the same problem with this.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways you can do that...but certainly it's probably better o build some sort of console applications for your case.

Frankly the simplest of which could be a windows schedule task that would trigger every day and launch an exe program (that you'd write using console dotnet) that would check soon-to-expire users and send an email when found...
If you don't want to have user + email code in various places (and centralize all this in your dotnet web app), then I'd create a SOAP/REST end point in your .NET webapp that would be called by a thin client, which would be scheduled by that "windows schedule task"

Quartz would give you more flexibility when it comes to scheduling and doing more enterprise things like job clustering / job high availability / job monitoring for example...
But that'd still be a .NET console app which would start a quartz scheduler, create a trigger, and run forever...(possibly wrapped into a windows "wrapper" service for more control)

Comment: how should I add the console project to my web app then? do u have a document link?